# Is it more efficent to assign a database query to a variable for a single view than to have multiple queries

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

If I want to count the number of people in a database several different ways, would it be more efficient to assign the initial `People.objects.all()` to a variable (version A below) than to query it each time.

Effectively, does **Version A** result in a single hit to the db, while **Version B** results in two?

**Version A:**

```
people_var = People.objects.all()
last_name_filter = people_var.filter(last_name='Doe').count()
first_name_filter = people_var.filter(first_name='John').count()
```

**Version B:**

```
last_name_filter = People.objects.filter(last_name='Doe').count()
first_name_filter = People.objects.filter(first_name='John').count()
```

Comment: It does not make a difference, in both versions, it will hit the database twice. Notice that `QuerySet`s are lazy, so the `people_var` is never performed, further even if it is, the `.filter(..)` makes a new queryset.

Comment: How might this be better structured? Cache the initial query and then work with the cache?

Comment: Well, you could always NOT perform `count()` for the same filter multiple times. If due to some reason the `last_name` value is not known to be similar or different, you can use a separate function that takes `last_name` as an argument and apply `lru_cache` decorator to it, so that for same `last_name`, cached result will be returned.

Comment: You probably have an error in you code above. You're querying for `last_name` in all the cases. Pretty sure that first query of both versions should query by `first_name` Please fix this in your question or indicate current filter is the correct one otherwise, as this makes the question unclear and hard to answer.

Comment: @rdik: because there is no cache, the `People.objects.all()` does *not* make a query.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Thanks for the catch. That was a typo... fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Effectively, does Version A result in a single hit to the db, while Version B results in two?

**No**, both will hit the database twice.

The `People.objects.all()` does *not* make a query. Indeed, `QuerySet` are *lazy*. That means that, unless you for example *iterate* over it, cal `len(…)` on it, etc., it does not *perform* the query on the database. It is thus basically a query that waits to be performed unless necessary.

Even if `people_var = Person.objects.all()` was performed - it is not, it would not mean that the `.filter(…)` functions would *use* that cache. Indeed, if you call `.all()`, or `.filter(…)` on a `QuerySet`, you make a *new*, *unevaluated* `QuerySet`.

Finally if you call `.count()` you do not make a `QuerySet`, it will thus result in making a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM …` query. So here you make two individual queries that will each count the number of objects. Even if both queries are identical, Django will make two queries. It is possible that the database will answer the second query faster, but that will be the same in both scenarios.

Comment: Adding to this answer: it is worth learning how and when Django is accessing the database and how it can be optimized by reading [Database access optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/optimization/) page from Django docs.